# LEAST and GREATEST date value from multiple tables, laravel way

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Is there any "Laravel-ish" way to capture the earliest and latest dates from multiple date fields in several laravel tables?

table for model1:

`fielda`| `fieldb`| `date1`

table2 for model2:

`fieldc`| `fieldd`| `date1`| `date2`

I couldn't find any elegant way to do it. My current approach is something like:

`$model1_dates = Model1::select(\DB::raw('MIN(date1) as min_date'), \DB::raw('MAX(date1) as max_date'))->get();
$model2_dates = Model2::select(\DB::raw('MIN(date2) as min_date'), \DB::raw('MAX(date2) as max_date'))->get();
$model2_dates2 = Model2::select(\DB::raw('MIN(date2) as min_date'), \DB::raw('MAX(date1) as max_date'))->get();`

afterwards, I will compare the results and get the minimum and maximum of those...

What approaches would be better?

Comment: In case of performance, I'd suggest to achieve this on MySQL side. Select from your tables, order by *, get first result & last result.

Comment: So, there isn't really any "Laravel" approach for this...

Comment: My first try was something like: ` $earliest_model1 = Model1::orderBy('idate1', 'asc')->pluck('date1')->first();`, but that will mean one more step to comparison

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used Laravel, but I'm not a fan - So I don't really know "Laravel-ish" or what it is. If you mean "something that looks simple", then it could be

```
$minDate = collect([
    Model1::min('date1'),
    Model2::min('date1'),
    Model2::min('date2'),
])->min();

$maxDate = collect([
    Model1::max('date1'),
    Model2::max('date1'),
    Model2::max('date2'),
])->max();
```

That's neat - But that are 6 queries to the DB.

A single raw SQL would be

```
select min(min_date) as min_date, max(max_date) as max_date
from (
    select min(date1) as min_date, max(date1) as max_date from table1
    union all
    select min(date1) as min_date, max(date1) as max_date from table2
    union all
    select min(date2) as min_date, max(date2) as max_date from table2
) x
```

or

```
select min(min_date) as min_date, max(max_date) as max_date
from (
    select min(date1) as min_date, max(date1) as max_date
    from table1
    union all
    select min(least(date1, date2))    as min_date,
           max(greatest(date1, date2)) as max_date
    from table2
) x
```

depending on what indexes you have. The first query performs better, when every date column has its own index.

Comment: I like your answer. Honest and pretty straight forward. This is what I could come up with. Can you help me check up the performance of this solution as well compared with yours? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/caa5e3/7

Comment: `FROM table1, table2` is a cross join - you can hardly do worse :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are functions like `max()`and `min()`. Also you can unite two queries with the `union()` method
[Aggregate Methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#aggregates)
[Union](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#unions)

And you can also use `orderBy` with laravel. Works also on dates.
[OrderBy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset)

Fastest way:

```
$minDateModel1 = Model1::min('date1');
$maxDateModel1 = Model1::max('date1');
```

Or:

```
$minDateModel1 = Model1::oldest('date1')->first()->pluck('date1');
$maxDateModel1 = Model1::latest('date1')->first()->pluck('date1');
```

Or:

```
$minDateModel1 = Model1::max('date1');

//should be the oldest first, newest at last
$minDateModel1 = Model1::orderBy('date1', 'asc')->first()->pluck('date1');
$maxDateModel1 = Model1::orderBy('date1', 'asc')->first()->pluck('date1');
```

Should do the trick:

```
$minDateModel1 = Model1::max('date1');
$minDateModel21 = Model2::max('date1');
$minDateModel22 = Model2::max('date2'); 
$allMinDates = $allMinDates->merge($minDateModel1);
$allMinDates = $allMinDates->merge($minDateModel21);
$allMinDates = $allMinDates->merge($minDateModel22);
$min = $allMinDates->min();
```

Comment: As I commented on the question comments thread, `OrderBy` was my first approach.

Comment: Edited the answer. Hope you like it and leave some upvotes.

Comment: I kind of simplified the code for clarity, I actual have at least 5 date fields in 3 different tables. @PaulSpiegel, could you please post an answer on how the SQL query should look like? Would this be a good case to use the `CASE` sql statement?

Comment: He asked for the laravelish way, it was never said that this is faster or better than sql. He also can run a raw sql query inside laravel. He also can define functions which will find the min and max for him and just call them on the query.

Comment: @AngelinCalu But a raw query is not "Laravel-ish".

Comment: @liqSTAR I just want to verify that for you "laravel-ish" is something like "neat code at any cost - performance doesn't matter".

Comment: I understand now that the "laravel-ish" approach is not the way to go for my current case. Thought it might be some helper method that I might be missing. If raw query is the way to go I will take that route :)

Comment: In laravel the easy way is one query for each column i want to find the min/max. Then i need to check the results again. In SQL you would join the table and do LEAST or GREATEST on the min/max of each column. But you also check every column. Still three queries in one query. Regarding the integer operations which needs to be done, i would say its the same amount of work. No matter what we prefer...the question is answered.

Comment: Any recommended approaches on the raw query?

Comment: Normal select, join any table with dates, then give the column names of each table into the LEAST function.
`LEAST(min(t1.date1),min(t2.date2),min(t2.date2),...)`

Comment: "Regarding the integer operations which needs to be done, i would say its the same amount of work" - It's not about number of "operations" at all. It's about latency. Don't underestimate the communication overhead of an SQL query even on a localhost DB. 6 queries vs 1 might be not much - But when you have 20 tables and like 50 date fields, then I would care.